# X button second click properties

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have an X button in an iPhone app.

Clicking it once makes the X button red. And clicking it a second time (after the X button is red) does the cancel action.

However, if someone clicks the X button (it is now red) and the clicks **outside** the X button, I want it to return to its original state.

How would I do this?

Comment: Hi you can try this.. - (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for a touch outside the button. If `button.isRed == TRUE`, then you should unred it.
Hope it's clear enough.

Say you've got `UIButton *closeButton`. Code'll be something like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    if ([touches anyObject].view == closeButton){
        //User touched in the button!
    } else {
        //User touched outside the button
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: "check for a touch outside the button" -- how?

Comment: this doesn't work when tapping on a button. In that case case the only button action will be triggered, this method won't be called.